# jquery polling with smart poll plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, get, polling, ajax-polling

I'm trying for the life of me to get this plugin to work but I'm not understanding the status function so retry is not firing.

```
$.poll(10000, function(retry){
  $.get('willfail', function(response, status){
    if (status == 'success') {
      // Do something
      alert("YES");
    } else {
      alert("NO");
      //retry();
    }
  })
})
```

If I set the get request to '/' it will give me the alert YES message, but as it is, the alert No message never gets fired despite the ELSE.

I'm using a jquery polling plugin:

https://github.com/jeremyw/jquery-smart-poll

Any ideas?

Comment: The code in `// Do something` may be silently failing so you never get to `alert("YES");` but also don't see `alert("NO");`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is probably a bad example. The callback passed to [**`$.get`**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) will only be fired if the request succeeded. Try this:

```
$.poll(10000, function(retry){
  $.ajax({
      url:'willfail',
      success: function(){
          // Do something
          alert("YES");
      },
      error: function() {
          alert("NO");
          retry();
      }
  });
});
```

For more information, have a look at [**`$.ajax`**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Answer (score 2):

You can also use Smartupdater - jQuery plugin

[http://www.eslinstructor.net/smartupdater/](http://www.eslinstructor.net/smartupdater3/)

which let you:

- Stop/Restart polling
- Change polling timeout dynamically
- Switch polling URL dynamically
- Switch callback function dynamically
- Remotely set polling timeout
- Remotely select callback function