# Looking for jQuery Poll script for asp.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-plugins, vbscript

I'm lokking for a Poll-script for Asp.Net VB, thats using jQuery.
I have seen this script [a link] http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/creating-a-dynamic-poll-with-jquery-and-php/

It's nice, clean but in PHP, do someone know if this is made for Asp.Net and not just some few code lines, but a full working ex. !?

Comment: http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=asp.net+jquery+polling I particularly like the first link explaining that there are lots of Ajax Poll scripts for ASP.NET but I would go for number 4 Nick Riggs version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look here:

[jquery polling with smart poll plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5665434/jquery-polling-with-smart-poll-plugin)

If you look for Jquery Plugins there are many pollings (:

http://speckyboy.com/2009/03/11/25-powerful-and-useful-jquery-tutorials-for-developers-and-designers/

Comment: Hi Alex. I can't find any vote/poll ex. on the 2. link u give me, and the first link is something for timing. have u seen the link i provided !? then u can see the poll and there is non polls in the link u provided me, im sry to say it..